# How to assign the text box value to a variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, selenium

I wanted to get the t@test.com value from the text box which has introduced as the (By.Id("Email")) and compare with the selectEmail value. I have used the following code, but it doesnot take any value which was saved from the text box in the text box. When I debug it I could get only null value for the foundEmail variable.

```
         var checkEmail = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Email"));
         string foundEmail = checkEmail.Text;
         string selectedEmail = "t@test.com";
         Assert.AreEqual(foundEmail, selectedEmail);
```

Please help me to assign the t@test.com value from the text box to the given variable called foundEmail.

Thankyou

Comment: What is the `driver` variable? Where does it come from and what's the `FindElement` method? Where does it come from? Also what's the `By` class and where does it come from?

Comment: Is the dot `.` after `checkEmail` in the second line intended?

Comment: @Darin This is a Selenium Web Driver Test File and thats how all of them come from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `checkEmail.Text` please use following code

`string foundEmail = driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).getAttribute("value"))`

Try it

Thanks.